# Example of MockValidationDataInherentDataProvider usage​

Tags: parachain, cumulus, documentation, mock, validation

Is there any example of how to use [MockValidationDataInherentDataProvider](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/primitives/parachain-inherent/src/mock.rs#L45) to run a parachain with mock validation? I've been looking all over and can't seem to find any documentation or example of it's usage, any resource on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to return it alone with other inherents. This is how Acala is using it.

https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/Acala/blob/e9a0f70efd341911bc6ccedd84411c1f9ab1d890/node/service/src/lib.rs#L290

```
        sc_consensus_aura::import_queue::<AuraPair, _, _, _, _, _, _>(ImportQueueParams {
            block_import: client.clone(),
            justification_import: None,
            client: client.clone(),
            create_inherent_data_providers: move |block: Hash, ()| {
                let current_para_block = client_for_cidp
                    .number(block)
                    .expect("Header lookup should succeed")
                    .expect("Header passed in as parent should be present in backend.");
                let client_for_xcm = client_for_cidp.clone();

                async move {
                    let timestamp = sp_timestamp::InherentDataProvider::from_system_time();

                    let slot = sp_consensus_aura::inherents::InherentDataProvider::from_timestamp_and_slot_duration(
                        *timestamp,
                        slot_duration,
                    );

                    let mocked_parachain = MockValidationDataInherentDataProvider {
                        current_para_block,
                        relay_offset: 1000,
                        relay_blocks_per_para_block: 2,
                        xcm_config: MockXcmConfig::new(
                            &*client_for_xcm,
                            block,
                            Default::default(),
                            Default::default(),
                        ),
                        raw_downward_messages: vec![],
                        raw_horizontal_messages: vec![],
                    };

                    Ok((timestamp, slot, mocked_parachain))
                }
            },
```

Comment: Thanks, that was extremely helpful, I got it working now!